# Rails - Cant get gsub to work to replace string text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gsub

I'm using the liquid gem and a wysiwyg editor for user posts. I'm trying to replace some of the content submitted before it is displayed. To do this I have tried .gsub but it isn't working at all

```
 <% template = Liquid::Template.parse(@category.template)  %>

 <% render = template.render(@keys_values_hash) %>

 <% content = render.gsub!('data-imgslap=', 'data-slap=') %>

 <% content.html_safe %>
```

The content is displayed fine and it all works but the text isnt replaced from gsub

I want it to just replace one thing so I know it works. But once that works I want to replace a couple of things. How would I use gsub to replace say `'text1', 'replacement1'` and `'text2', 'replacement2'` and why wont it work for just one replacement like I have setup now.

The data is stored as a string and grabbed from the db if that matters.

**Update**

Got it working. forgot to add the equal sign on `<%= on content.html_safe %>`

still got the problem of having 2 gsub changes on the one string here is what I have which doesnt change any coding

```
 <% template = Liquid::Template.parse(@category.template)  %>

 <% render = template.render(@keys_values_hash) %>

  <%  
  replacements = [ ['data-imgslap=', 'src='], [' src="http://i.imgur.com/bEDR9dc.png"', ''] ]
  replacements.each {|replacement| render.gsub(replacement[0], replacement[1])}
  %>

 <%=  render.html_safe %>
```

Got this from another question on stackoverflow but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: try `gsub` without exclamation mark

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I have and it still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, don't use multi-line statements in ERB.  Make it two lines.  And use `gsub!` to change the `render` object.

```
<% replacements = [ ['data-imgslap=', 'src='], ['src="http://i.imgur.com/bEDR9dc.png"', ''] ] %>
<% replacements.each {|replacement| render.gsub!(replacement[0], replacement[1])} %> 
<%=  render.html_safe %>
```

Comment: I really don't think "changing the render object" is a wise thing to do.

Comment: It's just a string, no?